# Passing message between fragments using interface

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, interface

I am currently learning the concept of fragments and message passing between them using interface. I have created a fragment container activity which initially holds the first fragment (Home_pageFragment). It consists of editText and a send button. When the button is clicked the content of editText is passed using an interface to the second fragment (Menu_pageFragment) which displays it as a text view. My app runs but when we click the send button, instead of passing the message to 2nd fragment, the app simply gets terminated.

Can anyone please tell me what could be the reason for this?

Below is my Home_page.java : (fragment container activity)

```
    package com.technology.computer.mit.ctechmit;

    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    public class Home_page extends ActionBarActivity implements OnButtonPressListener{

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

            // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout

            Home_pageFragment firstFragment = new Home_pageFragment();

            // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an
            // Intent, pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments

            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();


        }

       @Override
        public void onButtonPressed(String msg) {

           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

               Menu_pageFragment menuFragment = new Menu_pageFragment();
               Bundle args = new Bundle();
               args.putString("message", msg);
               menuFragment.setArguments(args);

               FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

               // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
               // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back

               transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, menuFragment);
               transaction.addToBackStack(null);

               // Commit the transaction

               transaction.commit();
       }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar

            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_home_page, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        public void openSearch() {

        }

        public void openSettings() {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

 // Handle presses on the action bar items

switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_search:
                    openSearch();
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_settings:
                    openSettings();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

        }
    }
```

Below is my Home_pageFragment.java : (fragment 1)

```
package com.technology.computer.mit.ctechmit;


import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Home_pageFragment extends Fragment {


    OnButtonPressListener buttonListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            buttonListener = (OnButtonPressListener) getActivity();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onButtonPressListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_page, null);
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.send_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                EditText editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
                String message = editText.getText().toString();

                buttonListener.onButtonPressed(message);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

Here is my Menu_pageFragment.java : (fragment 2)

```
package com.technology.computer.mit.ctechmit;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Menu_pageFragment extends Fragment {

    public Menu_pageFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_page, container, false);
    }

}
```

And here is my OnButtonPressListener.java : (interface)

```
package com.technology.computer.mit.ctechmit;

public interface OnButtonPressListener {
    public void onButtonPressed(String msg);
}
```

Can anyone please help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send data from one `Fragment` to another,

```
Menu_pageFragment newFragment = new Menu_pageFragment();
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putString(key,value);
newFragment.setArguments(b);
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

and in `Menu_pageFragment`, use

```
String value=getArguments().getString(key);
```

Comment: I have already done that sir. Now I need to do the same thing using interface because its said it is not advisable to directly communicate between fragments and so it is better to use their parent activity which implements an interface to pass message between the two fragments. **Note:** I have edited my code but still i get the same problem.